# Build process failed validation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

Getting strange error while triggering private build.
Getting below Error on one build controller but same build definition passes if different build controller is selected.

Error: The build process failed validation. Details: Validation Error: The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\" + _TaskItem.ItemSpec + "\HFIManager"". Type 'ITaskItem' is not defined.The private implementation of activity '1: DynamicActivity' has the following validation error: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "_BuildTargetsOut". Type 'ITaskItem' is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When customize TFS build you need to deal with Workflow Foundation, and you need to double check warning in the workflow if you want to have a successful build.

Such error is usually due to an invalid workflow. First please double check if there are some error in your build process template such as below screenshot:

[image]

The designer shows an informational icon on each action that has “something wrong” in its configuration.

Since you have mentioned the error occurs on one special build controller but  passes on other build controller.  The build Controller's job is to queue build requests and send them to the "most available" build agent. The Agent's job is to perform the actual build.

Suggest you to compare **Build Controller Properties** for both the one worked and failed. Check the environment on the build agents, to narrow down if it's an environment issue. You could also perform some other builds in the failed control to see if similar error generated.